# Создать объект с ключами из одного массива, а значениями из другого

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, рекурсия

Есть массив юзеров с их id и именами.

```
const users = [
  {
      "id": "U043WGQLVEF",
      "profile": {
          "real_name": "Evangelos Milly",
      },
  },
  {
      "id": "U043WMCQ9K4",
      "profile": {
          "real_name": "Ignace Mantvydas",
      },
  },
  {
      "id": "U043Z6Y11GD",
      "profile": {
          "real_name": "Daniyal Dionysos",
      },
  },
  {
      "id": "U044EM1N6ES",
      "profile": {
          "real_name": "Goran Ainslie",
      },
  }
]
```

Отдельно есть массив id.

```
const id = ['U043WGQLVEF', 'U043Z6Y11GD', 'U044EM1N6ES'];
```

Как мне создать объект, где ключом будут id, а значениями соответствующие имена?
По типу:

```
const obj = {
  'U043WGQLVEF': "Evangelos Milly",
  'U043Z6Y11GD': "Daniyal Dionysos",
  'U044EM1N6ES': "Goran Ainslie"
}
```

Comment: Тут недавно такой вопрос уже задавали... А что получилось сделать у вас?

Comment: @SwaD, У меня получилось не очень красиво, но вроде результат есть.
`
const obj = {};
id.forEach((el) => {
  obj[el] = undefined;
});
for (const key in obj) {
  users.forEach((el) => {
    if(key === el.id) {
      obj[key] = el.profile.real_name;
    };
  });
};
`

Comment: Добавьте ваш скрипт в вопрос, так красивее будет и читабельнее

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сократить и оптимизировать ваш код.
Метод forEach всегда обходит весь массив целиком и его нельзя прервать, поэтому в вашем варианте вы обходили весь массив users столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве id.

```js
const users = [
  {
  "id": "U043WGQLVEF",
  "profile": {
      "real_name": "Evangelos Milly",
  },
  },
  {
  "id": "U043WMCQ9K4",
  "profile": {
      "real_name": "Ignace Mantvydas",
  },
  },
  {
  "id": "U043Z6Y11GD",
  "profile": {
      "real_name": "Daniyal Dionysos",
  },
  },
  {
  "id": "U044EM1N6ES",
  "profile": {
      "real_name": "Goran Ainslie",
  },
  }
];

const id = ['U043WGQLVEF', 'U043Z6Y11GD', 'U044EM1N6ES'];

const obj = {}; 
id.forEach((el) => { 
  const find = users.find((item) => item.id === el);
  obj[el] = find.profile.real_name; 
}); 

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно использовать метод [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
const result = id.reduce((object, cid) => {
    const user = users.find((user) => (user.id === cid));
    return {
        ...object,
        [user.id]: user.profile.real_name
    };
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

```js
const users = [{
    "id": "U043WGQLVEF",
    "profile": {
      "real_name": "Evangelos Milly",
    },
  },
  {
    "id": "U043WMCQ9K4",
    "profile": {
      "real_name": "Ignace Mantvydas",
    },
  },
  {
    "id": "U043Z6Y11GD",
    "profile": {
      "real_name": "Daniyal Dionysos",
    },
  },
  {
    "id": "U044EM1N6ES",
    "profile": {
      "real_name": "Goran Ainslie",
    },
  }
];

const id = ['U043WGQLVEF', 'U043Z6Y11GD', 'U044EM1N6ES'];
const obj = {};

for (const user of users) if(id.includes(user.id)) obj[user.id] = user.profile.real_name;

console.log(obj)
```